# Elasticsearch filter by unique value

Tags: elasticsearch

i would like to get only results which have a unique value for a field how can i do it ?

I can count it with

```
$params ['body'] ['aggs']['test_count'] = array(
            "cardinality" => array(
            "field" => "id",
            "precision_threshold"=> 00
        )

    );
```

but the results still appear how can i set a filter to get only value have a distinct id ?

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is the unique values, you can use a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to get them.

If you want the full document, the closest thing they have is the top hits aggregation. Refer specifically to the [field collapsing example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html#_field_collapse_example).